# Sort String Json Date

Tags: javascript, json, date, momentjs

I am getting date values like that: `"/Date(1560458281000)/"` from an array of objects. I just want to order these dates by descending and ascending. I am open to any examples with pure JavaScript and/or moment.js By the way, hours and minutes are important. I will show it like `2014/10/29 4:50`

```
let dateSorted = this.props.myObj.sort(function(a,b) {
  sorted= new Date(Number(a.Date.replace(/\D/g, ''))) - new 
  Date(Number(b.Date.replace(/\D/g, '')))
  return sorted;
})
```

This code doesn't work.

Comment: Some real sample data would help here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be carefull with your `sorted` variable, it's missing the `const / let` initializer, I would have written:

```js
let dateSorted = this.props.differences.sort(function(a,b) {
  const timeA = Number(a.Date.replace(/\D/g, ''))
  const timeB = Number(b.Date.replace(/\D/g, ''))

  return timeA - timeB;
})
```

And since your dates are in timestamp format you don't even need to convert them to date to compare them, you can substract the numbers dicrectly.

A simpler way would be to use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

```js
let dateSorted = this.props.differences.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.Date.localeCompare(b.Date)
})
```

Since your date would be properly ordered by using the alphabetical order.

Comment: @reeeact Can you show the actual value of `myObj` and also, can you expand a bit on what exactly doesn't work ?

Comment: You can prepend an unary operator here (+) instead of using Number()

Comment: @Kobe I dislike using opperator type coercion, I find explicit `Number` more explicity and less hacky. Also his original code was using `Number`

Answer (score 0):

This code should sort the code from highest to lowest, and the format the dates:

```js
data = [{Date:"/Date(1560457284000)/"},{Date: "/Date(1560458274000)/"},{Date:"/Date(1560458192000)/"}]

sorted = data.sort(({Date:a}, {Date:b}) => +b.replace(/\D/g, '') - +a.replace(/\D/g, ''))

sorted = sorted.map(({Date}) => ({Date: moment(+Date.replace(/\D/g, '')).format('YYYY/MM/DD H:mm')}))
console.log(sorted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#map` to convert your array of string into an array of momentjs instances, then sort it with `Array#sort` with `a - b` as return value (or `b - a` for a descending order).

```
dates.map(d => moment(+d.replace(/\D/g, ''))).sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

Example:

```js
let dates = [
  '/Date(1560458281000)/',
  '/Date(1560454528989)/',
  '/Date(1560450204150)/',
  '/Date(1560458450489)/'
];

// Replaces.
dates = dates.map(d => moment(+d.replace(/\D/g, '')));

// Sorts in ascending order (return b - a for desc).
dates.sort((a, b) => a - b);

// "dates" is containing your sorted date in momentjs instances now.
console.log(dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problem with that is that you are just sorting the dates, maybe he want to sort the object containing the date and so can not use map.

That was my understanding.